# How to create Campaign hierarchy using AdWords MutateJobService?

Tags: google-ads-api

What's the least expensive way to create the entire Campaign hierarchy, from the Campaign down to the Ads/Keywords, using the AdWords API?

I have a tool for creating/organizing Campaigns, AdGroups, and Ads/Keywords. I'm sending this data to Google via the AdWords API.

Is there a way to do all of this in one single [MutateJobService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/bulkjobs.html#mutatejob)?

From all my research it seems the only way to do this is by

1. Creating the Campaigns job.
2. waiting for it to finish, extracting all Campaign ids and matching them to the AdGroups.
3. Creating an AdGroups job.
4. waiting for it to finish, extracting all AdGroup ids and matching them to the ads/keywords.
5. Creating an Ads/Keywords job.

Is there a simple way that I'm somehow missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to add an entire account hierarchy in a single job, because of depending IDs.  In general the number of campaigns and ad groups in an account is relatively small, and it may be worth using the synchronous CampaignService and AdGroupService to create them instead of waiting on jobs.

FYI: In the future you may want to post these questions to the official AdWords API forum: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/

Comment: I was afraid of that. The requirements for this project dictate a large number of adgroups, so I'm using the bulk service to speed up the process (synchronous calls are too slow.)

Comment: I've tried the official AdWords forum, but found it less helpful than StackOverflow. The community at SO is faster and more solution-oriented :)